# Работа с датой в Javascript

Tags: дата, javascript

Есть дата такого вида: 06-11-13.
Нужно при нажатии на кнопку прибавлять или вычитать один день.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали?

Comment: @RubaXa,пробовал делать split по строке,а потом прибавлять +1 к значению дня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас строка представляет дату в формате dd-mm-yy. Чтобы корректно ее распарсить, нужно поменять местами значение месяца и дня.

Например так:

```
var rawDateString = '06-11-13'
var dateArray = rawDateString.split('-');
var dateString = dateArray[1] + '/' + dateArray[0] + '/' + dateArray[2];
var dt = new Date(dateString); // Nov 06 2013 00:00:00
```

Впрочем, если ваша строка означает не 6 ноября 2013 года, а 11 июня 2013, то вышесказанное можно пропустить.

Чтобы прибавить к дате день можно сделать так:

```
dt = dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
dt = new Date(dt);  // Nov 07 2013 00:00:00
```

С кнопками, надеюсь, разберётесь сами

Comment: @DreamChild,конечный результат dt=Invalid Date.Моя строка означает 6 ноября

Comment: @Denis Makarenko поправил ответ. У вас судя по всему FireFox? В нём предыдущий вариант не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
function nextDate(ddmmyy){
   var date = new Date(ddmmyy.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/, function (_,dd,mm,yy){
      if( yy.length == 2 ){ yy = (new Date().getFullYear()+'').substr(0, 2) + yy; }
      return [yy, mm, dd].join('/');
   }));
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
   return date;
}

nextDate("06-11-13"); // Thu Nov 07 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (MSK)
nextDate("06-11-1813"); // Sun Nov 07 1813 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
```

Comment: @RubaXa,возвращает Invalid Date.

Comment: Вы правы, поправил.

Comment: А почему бы и нет, просто тест :]